# Angular 6 Error... calendar.component has no exported member 'CalendarComponent'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I report here a issue, hoping some pious souls could help..
Here's the problem, Node gives me this ERROR:

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(11,10): error TS2305: Module
>   '"V:/Projects/Kompany/source/kompany-war/src/main/websrc/test2/test-kompany/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.component"'
>   has no exported member 'CalendarComponent'.
>   src/app/components/calendar/calendar.component.ts(27,3): error TS2390:
>   Constructor implementation is missing.
>   src/app/components/oculus/oculus.component.ts(2,34): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'components/calendar/calendar.component'.
>   src/app/components/top-menu/top-menu.component.ts(2,10): error TS2305:
>   Module
>   '"V:/Projects/Kompany/source/kompany-war/src/main/websrc/test2/test-kompany/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.component"'
>   has no exported member 'CalendarComponent'.

Here's the sitauation..

I have this on the app module...

```
 `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` 
 `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';`
 `import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';`
 `import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';`


import { CalendarComponent } from'./components/calendar/calendar.component';
```

What I'm trying to do is putting a calendar library into my site.

The error is on a component I created ( Calendar Component ) and on which I put all the information I found on the web in order to try it..

https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/docs/index.html

this is where I downloaded the library.

I'm new to Angular so I'm giving all the info I have, hope not to be boring.

Into Calender Component here is what's there...

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarEvent } from 'angular-calendar';


 @Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html'
 })
 export class DemoComponent {
   view: string = 'month';

   viewDate: Date = new Date();

 events: CalendarEvent[] = [
  {
    title: 'Click me',

    start: new Date()
   },
 {
   title: 'Or click me',

   start: new Date()
 }
];
 constructor ()
 ngOnInit() {

 }

  eventClicked({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void {
    console.log('Event clicked', event);
     }
  }
```

I read on the site that this error is due to Angular's infrastructure as I got..
And some answers to similar topics where about ordering the imports, but they are already in order.

I really don't know what to do.. hope someone will be helpful..

Lots of smiles

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of errors, all of which angular is complaining about.

1. There is no exported class called 'CalendarComponent' in the file
   you listed - in that file you export a class called 'DemoComponent'
   instead.
2. In line 27 of your component.ts file  you have no definition for the
   constructor.  You have `constructor ()` but you should have
   `constructor() {}` if you want it to be empty.
3. It looks like you are also attempting to import the wrongly named
   class in two other components, named 'oculus.component.ts', and
   'top-menu.component.ts'